# How to fix an UnsatisfiedLinkError (Can't find dependent libraries)

Tags: java, dll, unsatisfiedlinkerror

I am having an issue when loading a dll file using java. I am getting 
`java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Unable to load library 'C:\Users\GZammit\Documents\gapt\RwLibraries': Native library (win32-x86-64/C:\Users\GZammit\Documents\gapt\RwLibraries.dll) not found in resource path ...`

This is my code :

```
ClassApi INSTANCE = (ClassApi) Native.loadLibrary(System.getProperty("user.dir")+"\\RwLibraries\\renderwarriors", ClassApi.class);
```

I did a lot of research and I know there are many with same error but none of the solutions worked for me. The weird thing is, it shows you which files it searched and one of the files is the **actual** path of the dll location. I even printed out both urls to confirm. I also placed the dll in many other location including the sysWOW64.

I also changed the java.library.path before loading the dll to make sure it is in that particular path without success either. I also followed multiple tutorials online doing exactly the same code without success.

I am using jna 4.4.0 jar file and jna-platform 4.4.0 . I checked the java path and also placed a dll in one of the paths mentioned.

There should be no error code-wise since it worked for my team but not on my computer. I also tried on two different computers.

Everything is 64-bit including the dll.

Comment: You should supply the undecorated library name to `loadLibrary`, not the path. i.e. the filename minus the `.dll`.

Comment: I tried that approach as well but didn't work. I also did it right after setting the java.library.path to the path where the dll is found

Comment: Can you show that code as well? You might also try setting `jna.library.path`.

Comment: `System.setProperty("java.library.path",System.getProperty("user.dir"));
        ClassApi INSTANCE = (ClassApi) Native.loadLibrary("RwLibraries",ClassApi.class);`

I also tried giving a static path.

Comment: Isn't the library called `renderwarriors`?

Comment: my mistake, that is what I wrote but I just rewrote it now because I removed that line of code. But yes you are right, the dll is called renderwarriors. So the actual code I tried was : 

`System.setProperty("java.library.path",System.getProperty("u‌​ser.dir")); ClassApi INSTANCE = (ClassApi) Native.loadLibrary("renderwarriors",ClassApi.class);`

Comment: So then it seems the `java.library.path` should be `System.getProperty("u‌​‌​ser.dir") + "\\RwLibraries"`. But you can also try setting that to `jna.library.path`.

Comment: Just tried it like so but didn't work :

`System.setProperty("java.library.path", System.getProperty("user.dir")+"\\RwLibraries");
        System.setProperty("jna.library.path", System.getProperty("user.dir")+"\\RwLibraries");
        ClassApi INSTANCE = (ClassApi) Native.loadLibrary( "renderwarriors",ClassApi.class);`

Honestly I don't think it is a problem with code since my team can access it without any problems. But we have the same dependencies and everything